# iPhone 5 Wrong Screen Height

Tags: ios, ios5

I have developed an app on the 3.5 inch Screen and now I did a new Storyboard for the 4 inch screen and I do like follows to switch between storyboards on the appdelegate and I logged the screen height and it gives me 480.00000 check it:

```
NSLog(@"Checking Screen Size");
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{    
    NSLog(@"On iPhone");
    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
    {   (diagonally measured)
        NSLog(@"iPhone 4: %f", iOSDeviceScreenSize.height);
}
if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
{   
        NSLog(@"iPhone 5: %f", iOSDeviceScreenSize.height);
}
```

The NSLog gives me 480.0000 while my phone is iPhone 5

Comment: Do you have the 568px tall startup image (Default.png)? If not, you won't be started in full screen mode.

Comment: I will try it now. and get back to you. Thanks for the help:D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a "tall" startup image `Default-568h@2x.png` to the app to indicate that you support the new display size, otherwise you'll be run in compatibility mode (and not full screen).

Answer (score 3):

You should add a new default image `Default-568h@2x.png` to the project.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, just add **`Default-568h@2x.png`** which is Default image for iPhone 5 to the project.