# xcode when i run program on iphone 5 screen looks iphone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm using Xcode 6 and use objective-c when i test program on iOS 8 (iPhone 5) program run without error but when i try to test program on iOS 7 (iPhone 5) screen look like iPhone 4 screen. I can detect phone like this;

```
#define iPhone6Plus ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736)
#define iPhone6 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
#define IS_IPAD UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

and also i can detect operating system like this;

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0)
{
    #define IS_IPHONE_5 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
}
```

When i do this screen not scale on phone because when i run on iOS 7 phone screen run like iPhone 4 check image for more description.
[image]

As you can see top and bottom black.How can i fix this problem

Comment: You're just missing a default.png for iPhone5 screens. If you add it it will work as expected without edges.

Comment: I haven't got default.png and when i run on iOS 8 these black screen not appear

Comment: You must include correct images otherwise nothing is guarantied. What you experience happens if you don't have correct image.

Comment: How can i includes this images ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12396545/1032151 Also @hasan83's answer is correct, it's just hard to understand right (i.e. answer needs improvements).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 5 Wrong Screen Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038077/iphone-5-wrong-screen-height)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Set an iPhone 5 launch screen. It will be fixed.

iPhone 5 launch screen spec: **640x1136**

For the time being create a blank screen on photoshop or preview. You can replace it later.

Comment: How can i fix this, i know screen spec when i test iOS 8 program running without error and I'm testing on phones not emulator

Comment: Create an image with a graphic app. like photoshop. then add it from the "General" tab setting.

Comment: Actually i have got screen for iPhone 5 size, my problem different

Comment: What about the specs of the image and are you shire its set on the right place?