# Debug on iOS device gives wrong screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, retina

I'm trying to run my application on an iPod 5 (4inch retina screen) but it shows the 3,5 inch version of the application.

On an iPhone 5S it does show the correct screen size. Are there any known settings to accomplish a setup like this and how can I turn it off again?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546641/xcode-when-i-run-program-on-iphone-5-screen-looks-iphone-4

Comment: This was indeed something I checked, but as these are provided I think the problem is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you also have to assign the Image asset to the project. In your target you see the asset to choose from in the 'app icon and launch images' section, here it pointed to an old & renamed asset.

Changed it to the correct one, removed the derived data and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have all the images set in the LaunchImages.
You can find this in the images.xcassets of your project in xcode.

Comment: I have all default images that are needed. Also, it works without issue on an iPhone 5S which should use the same default image