# Blank screen in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

when I update my Xcode to Xcode7 ,when I launch my apps on iphone 6(not simulator) ,it will show LanuchScreen.xib first,and then the screen will be black(with only battery icon in right-top corner).In Xcode6 it is all ok.What is wrong with it???

Comment: have u checked in simulator for iphone6

Comment: Did you run the app connected to Xcode? Does the Xcode show any error?

Comment: can you show the screen shot

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No he can not. Too low reputation.

Comment: you see like this type answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546641/xcode-when-i-run-program-on-iphone-5-screen-looks-iphone-4

Comment: Upload all the launch images with correct sizes and then retry.

Comment: hi try to post the question by replying to all @Zhang Haoran

Comment: Xcode does not show any error, in simulator it does work,but in iphone it could not show anything but only a battery icon

Comment: @Uma it can only show the screen shot

Comment: @ZhangHaoran have u checked with iOS version of device with the required deployment target

Comment: I create a new project it works fine.I think the info.plist or the project configuration file has something wrong,but I don not know How to fix it.

Comment: @Uma the target is 9.0

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `default@2x.png` image is not a valid `png` image. Please try replacing your existing `default@2x.png` image with a new valid one and it should work.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the gitHub link to your project so I could take a look.

Comment: I am sorry,the project is outsourcing,will be commit to the company soon.I could not find the same problem in Internet.

Comment: Thats fine. I understand! Let me think and throw more ideas.

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219291/black-screen-instead-of-launch-image-on-ipad-ios-7-0-x). It has a potential workaround to similar issue. See if this helps you. Also, take a look at the accepted answer. It seems to be a known reported bug to Apple.